# × TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am new to js, I am getting an error at the line `this.state = { location: props.history.location};`
as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`, how to fix the problem providing my code below :

```
function App() {

    return (
        //BEM naming convention
        <div className="app">
            <div className="app_body">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Sidebar />
                        <Route path="/root/:roomId">
                            <Chat />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/">
                            <h1>Home screen</h1>
                            <Chat />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        </div>

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put up the snippet that you're trying to execute? I would appreciate it if you elaborate on what output you are expecting.

From what I understand, you might what to try adding this before your `return()` :

```
const location = useLocation();
```

If you use Class Component then try this inside the `render()` method before the `return()` codeblock :

```
const { location } = this.props;
```

Then you can just go on and use `location`.